# Google Apps Script - Editor shortcut - CTRL+D

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

The Google Apps Script's Editor has updated, and mostly for the better, but there is only one thing missing :
Ctrl+ D (delete the line) is not working anymore!

Do you know how to add a custom shortcut or any workaround ?

PS: I found out that CTRL+X is now cutting the line if nothing selected, which is great.
But CTRL+D was more efficient without replacing the clipboard content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new editor, in order to delete a line, you can press:

**Windows:**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>

**Mac IOS:**
<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: thanks, and do you know if there is a way to custom those shortcuts?